# UIButton selector not work

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, selector

I can't call buttonAction method, when i click nothing happen. I used the last #selector of swift 2.2 and my `buttonAction` function is already outside `notificationAlert` function.

```
class AlertHelper: UIViewController {

    var cancel_button: UIButton!

    func notificationAlert(message:String, viewController : UIViewController, color: UIColor) {

        cancel_button = UIButton(
            frame: CGRect(
                x: viewController.view.center.x,
                y: viewController.view.center.y + 50,
                width: 100,
                height: 50
            )
        )

        //Bind Click on Button ERROR
        cancel_button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AlertHelper.buttonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        viewController.view.addSubview(cancel_button)

    }

    class func displayError(message:String, viewController : UIViewController) {
        AlertHelper().notificationAlert(message, viewController: viewController, color : .whiteColor())
    }

    func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!)
    {
       print("ok")
    }
}
```

Comment: from where are you calling `displayError` function

Comment: I am assuming you are calling this method from some other view controller. As the `AlertHelper` class no longer exist in your memory, you won't be able to access its `buttonAction` since you are not keeping AlertHelper class object always in the memory and just calling its class function

Comment: Yes that's right call this method from sole other view controller. So, how i can keep AlertHelper in memory ? How i can fix my code?

Comment: one way is to use delegates with UIButton and you can just implement the delegates in your view controller

Comment: Another way is to create a shared instance of your `AlertHelper`. As you can see that You are again creating new object of `AlertHelper` in displayError function. I will be posting a solution in a minute

Comment: Posted the solution. Check out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `AlertHelper` class as follows and make that a singleton class

```
class AlertHelper: UIViewController {

    var cancel_button: UIButton!

    // Here is your static object that will always remain in memory
    static let sharedInstance = AlertHelper()

    func notificationAlert(message:String, viewController : UIViewController, color: UIColor) {

        cancel_button = UIButton(
            frame: CGRect(
                x: viewController.view.center.x,
                y: viewController.view.center.y + 50,
                width: 100,
                height: 50
            )
        )

        //Bind Click on Button ERROR
        cancel_button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AlertHelper.buttonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        viewController.view.addSubview(cancel_button)

    }

    func displayError(message:String, viewController : UIViewController) {
        //Maintaining the same static object and not making any new object
        AlertHelper.sharedInstance.notificationAlert(message, viewController: viewController, color : .whiteColor())
    }

    func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

    print("ok")

    }

}
```

Now in your other controller you can all as follows:

```
AlertHelper.sharedInstance.displayError("Check", viewController: self)
```

And you are done. Click will work!